# Why document.write("-->") does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

```
<p>hello</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<!--");
</script>
<p>world</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("-->");
</script>
<p>nihao</p>
```

I thought the output of this piece of HTML is

```
hello
nihao
```

But it turns out as below:

```
hello
");
nihao
```

How should I achieve what I expected? What's the problem here?

Comment: What is the output? (full HTML)

Comment: I can't give you a rational reason why it doesn't work, but this feels so *wrong*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the first JavaScript element is executed which leads to a representation like this:

```
<p>hello</p>
<!--
<p>world</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("-->");
</script>
<p>nihao</p>
```

So the HTML comment start you just added spans into your next JavaScript element and the resulting output is just as you described. To answer your second question, whats wrong with the following?

```
<p>hello</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<!--<p>world</p>-->");
</script>
<p>nihao</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is because the `<!--` in your javascript is parsed as the start of a comment before the JavaScript runs.

Comment: But isn't his problem that it's *not*  parsed as the start of a comment?

Comment: I think that was intentional.

Comment: This answer now makes sense :) Sorry.

Comment: It is only parsed as a comment before the JS runs if the document is served as `application/xhtml+xml` and there is no suggestion that it is. If it was parsed as a comment before the JS ran, then it wouldn't render the `");`

Answer (score 5):

There have been some useful answers, but if you actually want to create a comment and insert it into your document then you need to use the [`createComment()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createComment):

```
var comment = document.createComment("This is a comment") 
​document.appendChild(comment);​
```

Will output:

```
<!--This is a comment-->
```

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly result you expect:

```
<p>hello</p>
<script id="ahh" type="text/javascript">
document.write("<!"+"--"+"<p>world<p>--"+">");
document.getElementById('ahh').remove()
</script>
<p>nihao</p>​
```

anyway it is pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you came across this question wanting to hide an element when JavaScript is enabled, consider using the `<noscript>` tag instead!